# AS3 - need timeline to go back to frame 1 when another button gets clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, button

When rect_button is clicked it goes to frame 5. I am trying to figure out how to get it to return to frame 1 when another button gets clicked.

So far, I can get my first button (rect_button) to go to 5.

```
stop()

rect_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(5);
}
```

What do I do to so that "rect_button" goes back to frame 1 when "rect_button2" gets clicked?
I am a complete beginner so I am a bit lost. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that rect_button2 is on frame 5, and this all has to do with the mane timeline, then it should be the same exact thing:

```
// On frame 5
stop()

rect_button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame2);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  gotoAndStop(1);
}
```